# using variable in cmake as define

Tags: cmake

I have problem of a defined string
If I have in sources code

```
static const QStringList g_arrGenersControllerCommonLibDefinitions(QString(U_LIBS).split(";"));
```

How can I specify in cmake that he writes to a variable
like this

```
add_definitions(-DU_LIBS="${U_LIBS}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I specify in cmake

The problem not in CMake only but also in gcc. When you pass definition through CMake it arrives to gcc without escaping. You can try `make VERBOSE=1` to see it.

Here is a solution:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project (CMPD)
find_package (Qt5Core REQUIRED)

set (U_LIBS)
set (U_LIBS "${U_LIBS}/usr/lib/libu.so")
set (U_LIBS "${U_LIBS}\\\;/usr/lib/libu.so.0")
set (U_LIBS "${U_LIBS}\\\;/usr/lib/libu.so.0.0")
set (U_LIBS "${U_LIBS}\\\;/usr/lib/libu.so.0.0.0")
add_definitions(-DU_LIBS="${U_LIBS}")

add_executable (cmpd ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cmpd Qt5::Core)
```

Output:

```
("/usr/lib/libu.so", "/usr/lib/libu.so.0", "/usr/lib/libu.so.0.0", "/usr/lib/libu.so.0.0.0")
```

The sources are available [here](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/45773184).